# In app browser wont load

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios

I have an app in app browser which shows a website using the intel xdk.

The website loads in app browser in the emulator and on my windows phone (but the images don't display), however it will not load on my ipad. The screen remains blank.

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <!-- * Please see the included README.md file for license terms and conditions.  -->
    <head>
        <title>Window.open</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <!-- see http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-     tutorials/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,  minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0;"/>
        <style>
            /* following two viewport lines are equivalent to meta viewport statement above, needed for Windows */
            /* see    http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2014/05/html5_dev_conf.html and  http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-device-adapt/ */
            @-ms-viewport { width: 100vw ; min-zoom: 100% ; zoom: 100% ; }      @viewport { width: 100vw ; min-zoom: 100% zoom: 100% ; }
            @-ms-viewport { user-zoom: fixed ; min-zoom: 100% ; }            @viewport { user-zoom: fixed ; min-zoom: 100% ; 
        </style>
        <!-- Uncomment "phantom" cordova.js script if you convert your   "Standard HTML5" project into a "Cordova" project. -->
        <!-- <script src="cordova.js"></script> -->          <!-- phantom library, needed for Cordova api calls, added during build -->
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>           <!-- recommended location of your JavaScript code relative to other JS files -->
        <script src="xdk/init-dev.js"></script>     <!-- normalizes device and document ready events, see README for details -->
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script>
            function openwin(){
                window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com', '_blank', '');
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="openwin()">window open>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have which iOS version? Width definition  with vw has some issues with iOS 6 and 7 and is not available on earlier at all. Works only in iOS 8 for sure.

Comment: My testing device is an Ipad that runs IOS8 it is an iPad 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact this is not an in app browse in offical concept, you are just throwing away your code and leaving some page instead. It works fine in webborwsers but will give you some problems in HTML5 apps once there will not be secure code anymore.

An in app browser mean you are creating some container and inside this container you load some website, this works in a secure way.

Once you are using Intel XDK, a command you may try is:

`intel.xdk.device.showRemoteSiteExt("http://www.stackoverflow.com",280,0,50,50,60,60);`

[This article](http://qnimate.com/launch-browser-inside-intel-xdk-app/) may be a start point to help you. And [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/493057) is the description of the method i sugested.